# Struct with multiple Array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a small issue with array's in struct.
I need a (constant) struct of char array's with length 2.
They will be the command of my uart message (2 chars).

When I print the array value of 2chars, All the chars after that point will be printed. But I only need 2 items, how can if do this properly.

In total I will have around 125 instructions

```
struct Test_struct {
 char a[2]={'a','a'};
 char b[2]={'b','b'};
 char c[2]={'c','c'};
};
const struct Test_struct Test;
Tfunc(Test.b);


void Tfunc(const char *funct)
{
  cout << funct;
}
```

easy way to make an list of instructions. 1 instruction is a char of 2 elements.

in the futere I like to use something like this.
Command.Network.ID
ID wil be my char of 2. Network will be a struct that contains all network commands. An other list of commans will be Security or IO, …
and a global struct command. It must be an struct.

while I'm programming I like to type command. and select a subgroep and select an instruction. Then I don't need to search in a big list.
I don't like: const char[2] ID = ...
              const char[2] …

Do you have some tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<<` operator on `std::cout` expects a `char*` to be null-terminated. Your `char` arrays do not have a null terminator, which is why it will just continue printing until it happens to meet a 0 in memory (or crash). If all you want is to have a bunch of global constants for different commands, consider using, e.g., a namespace with a bunch of `std::string_view` constants instead:

```
#include <string_view>

namespace Commands
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    inline constexpr auto a = "aa"sv;
    inline constexpr auto b = "bb"sv;
    inline constexpr auto c = "cc"sv;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the info. Don't know eactly how it works. But google knows how it works.

Comment: @MarnixVolders I can try to improve the explanation if you let me know which part specifically you're finding hard to understand…

Comment: Michael Kenzel, thnx for the response. I never used namespaces before. I tried it on my Raspbarry Pi, but it doesn't know <String_view>

i tried something else because commands change depending on Hardware type. At this point (testing i use Through Hole IC, at next step when i design my PCB i will use SMT IC. So i have some work to doe :) . The only thing i have to do is search in my list of Enums witch command i need. i have a total of +-140 commands. 

What i tried to do, i don't want to search in my enum, but start typing and the pop up will filter the command